# Finding 'Nginx.conf'

Tags: wordpress, nginx, vagrant, virtualbox

I recently started using vagrant and Virtualbox to run my Wordpress website. Today I ran into a problem. I was trying to import a theme and this happened.

> 413 Request Entity Too Large --- nginx/1.6.2 (Ubuntu).

I think that I know how to solve this, but for that i need to have access to the nginx.conf file. How do I access this where do I find it? 
I' m using a mac.

Comment: Generally the file would be in the directory /usr/local/nginx/conf, /etc/nginx, or /usr/local/etc/nginx on your VM depending how the installation was done

Comment: is there a way to do this through the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would need to login into the VM - you can do `vagrant ssh` to do so.
Once on the VM, you would need to edit your `nginx.conf` file as sudo (nginx.conf file is generally located in the directory /usr/local/nginx/conf, /etc/nginx, or /usr/local/etc/nginx on your VM depending how the installation was done) so `sudo vi nginx.conf` from the correct directory and you can make the change.

make sure to restart nginx after you made the change `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart` from the VM or even restart the VM if you make many changed `vagrant reload` from the host and you'll be ok

Comment: do a `sudo find / -name nginx.conf` and let it search

Comment: Found it, Thanks a lot!